# Initializing serialization for derived classes in protobuf

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I am using protobuf. I have abstract class base1.cs and another class ListofItems.cs which has list of base1 and some other properties.

This is how I initialize serializer

```
private static MetaType Actualmodel; 

static Initserialization()
    {
            var Model = TypeModel.Create();
                Model.Add(typeof (EventMessage), true);
                Actualmodel= Model.Add(typeof (base1), true);
                ProtobufSerializer.Models.Add(typeof(ListofItems), Model);
    }
```

I have bunch of  of objects which inherit from base1.cs and everything works fine. 
Now I am adding another class base2.cs which inherits from base1. How do I update Initialization to include this base2?

tried below but does not work

```
 Actualmodel= Model.Add(typeof (base1), true).AddSubType(500,typeof(base2));
```

Thanks!

Comment: You say "does not work": what happens? nothing? an exception? your computer belches black smoke then dies? give me a clue here ;p

Comment: lol by does not work means i meant it does nothing

Comment: @user570715: Not many lines of code 'do nothing'. You should probably try and be more specific. Ideally, provide a broken test or something that can reproduce the issue